# Google Geo Chart Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 3 columns)

Tags: google-visualization

I have the following code and found Incompatible data table: Error: Table contains more columns than expected (Expecting 3 columns)

```
function drawMarkersMap() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['State',                             'User', 'Company','data'],
    ['Australian Capital Territory',       100,        160, 100],
    ['Northern Territory',                 250,        250, 200 ],
    ['Western Australia',                  150,        350, 300],
    ['New South Wales',                    300,        100, 400],
    ['Victoria',                           50,         156, 50],
    ['Queensland',                         10,         150, 20],
    ['South Australia',                    160,        168, 23],
    ['Tasmania',                           250,        568, 3443]
    ]);

  var options = {
    region : 'AU',
    displayMode : 'markers',
    colorAxis : {
      colors: ['blue', 'red']
    }

  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div_geo'));
chart.draw(data, options);

};
```

Answer (score 7):

Geocharts do not support having 3 different data columns as you have.

### Region Charts

For region charts, the data should include only:

1. Region (Country, Subcontinent, Continent, etc.)
2. Color (Determines color for each region based on a single data category)

### Marker Charts

For marker charts, the data should include only:

1. Location (either latitude/longitude, or a string indicating location)
2. (optional) Name of Location for Latitude/Longitude Locations only
3. Color (color of the marker based on a single data category)
4. Size (size of the marker based on a single data category)

Currently your example is a marker chart with a third data category, which isn't supported (your `User` will determine color, and `Company` will determine size).

Comment: @user What are you looking to show? You have two things you can change (color and size), but three types of data you want to show (user, company, and data). You can't show all three. So what do you want to show?

Answer (score 4):

This is your solution:

```
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([0, {
type: 'number',
label: 'Total Staff',
calc: function (dt, row) {
    return {
        v: dt.getValue(row, 1),
        f: dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1) + ' (' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 2) + ' IT, ' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 3) + ' HR, ' + dt.getFormattedValue(row, 4) + ' Sales)'
    }
}
}]);

 chart.draw(view, {...
```

Comment: This is very helpful! It would be useful if you could provide a description. I'd be curious how to do something like this to the second column and leave the first column in tact to use html. +1